# Trouble using PIP Install

Tags: cmd, pip, package

Having trouble installing any packages or upgrading through PIP install. basically i want to install packages for Data Science. Not able to use CONDA either.

Error I got-

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement menuinst (from conda) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for menuinst (from conda)
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: _Anaconda supports Python 2.7, 3.6, and 3.7._  Bad success for 3.8? In any case, upgrade `pip` as adviced…

Comment: Not even able to upgrade pip, neither the conda is working, there is some system problem preventing me to upgrade or install any package